# Clean skin without any 'special effects' styling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a free clean bootstrap skin without any css3 gradients and thousand lines of code, which i need to overwrite (like rounded corners, transitions, advanced gradient backgrounds etc.)

Basically, something like this would be great but it's commercial: http://codecanyon.net/item/modern-bootstrap-clean-skin/3227276

Thanks in advance

Comment: Although I can't provide an answer, wouldn't it make sense just to start from a Reset and develop forward? Bootstrap offers the core essentials to develop most interfaces w/o a designer. Or use other skin libs that match your needs (which are all pretty big)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flatstrap](http://littlesparkvt.com/flatstrap/) is a third-party version of Bootstrap that fulfills your requirements.

*"Sometimes a new project doesn't need rounded corners or gradients. So we decided to get rid of them."*

Answer (score 0):

Tons of skins here: https://wrapbootstrap.com/

(not free, but if 10-$20 is too much then you are in the wrong business!)